# how to find $ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2 +1} +\sqrt{4x^2 + 1} - \sqrt{9x^2 + 1}\right)$

Tags: limits, radicals

How can I find this?

$ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2 +1} +\sqrt{4x^2 + 1} - \sqrt{9x^2 + 1}\right)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2 +1} +\sqrt{4x^2 + 1} - \sqrt{9x^2 + 1}\right) =\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \left(\sqrt{x^2 +1}-x +\sqrt{4x^2 + 1}-2x - (\sqrt{9x^2 + 1}-3x)\right) = $
$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 +1}+x}+\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4x^2 + 1}+2x} -\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{9x^2 + 1}+3x} = 0 + 0 + 0 = 0$

Comment: What is unclear?

Comment: Probably because you forgot the minus sign but otherwise I find your answer very good. I just picked ncmathaddict's answer because he answered first and it just didn't occur to me to add the extra $x_s$

Comment: I threw in the minus sign and a few limits.  You can rollback if it's not satisfactory.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another tack.  If $a > 0$, 
$${\sqrt{a^2 x^2 + 1} - ax } = {1\over{\sqrt{a^2 x^2 + 1} + ax }}= O\left
({1\over x}\right). $$

Comment: Very nice this trick!

Comment: This did it! It didn't occur to me to add and subtract the extra $x_s$.

Answer (score 1):

Since for any $A>0$
$$\sqrt{A^2 x^2+1}-A|x| = \frac{1}{A|x|+\sqrt{A^2 x^2+1}}<\frac{1}{2A|x|}$$
holds, we have:
$$\left|\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{4x^2+1}-\sqrt{9x^2+1}\right|=\left|\sqrt{x^2+1}-|x|+\sqrt{4x^2+1}-2|x|-\sqrt{9x^2+1}+3|x|\right|\leq \left|\sqrt{x^2+1}-|x|\right|+\left|\sqrt{4x^2+1}-2|x|\right|+\left|\sqrt{9x^2+1}-3|x|\right|<\frac{1}{|x|}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}\right),$$
hence the limit is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

A  heuristic result:

Note that $x$ ~$\sqrt{x^2 + 1}$ as $x \to \infty$, and similar results hold for the other terms. Thus the limit is seen to be zero.

To make the result more rigorous, observe what happens when you expand the result in Elias' answer using the binomial series.